# Redirect in MVC controller to another controller not working

Tags: model-view-controller

Hi Everyone , I am new to MVC but have programmed before. I have setup an error controller
which can be called when an error occurs in the main controller. My aim is to have one error view , which I can pass in the relevant error messages.

In the code below I am calling the error controller to displays the index view when there no record is returned from the product list

Here is my main controller

```
       public ActionResult Details(int ProductID)
    {   

        var model = db.Get(ProductID);
        if (model == null)
        {
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "ErrorController");
           return errorController.Index("Record not Found", "The Product you are looking for is no longer available");

        }

        return View(model);

    }
```

And this is my Error Controller that it calls successfully

```
     public ActionResult Index(string errorTitle, string errorMessage)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorTitle = errorTitle;
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        return View();
    }
```

At the moment the Index Action Result is called and the view returned but the details view from the original controller is also called, which causes an error as there is no records .
So my Error view is not being displayed .
How can I stop the original details view from being called ? 
Any help would be great 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new {
   ErrorTitle = "Record not Found",
   ErrorMessage = "The Product you are looking for is no longer available"
});
```

You basically need to redirect to the error controller and pass in the params as part of the route. RedirectToAction takes a parameter of `RouteValues`

`Also you do not need "ErrorController", you can just use "Error"`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so generally in .net you don't want to pass along errors with redirects like that, instead you should use a library like Vereyon.Web FlashMessageCore which will help you with redirecting errors to the user in an easy and concise way.

However, if you want to do it that way (totally fine) you still need to pass the error title and error message like so in the redirect to action call:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new {errorTitle="error", errorMessage="message"});
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice , I'm actually just building a small application for a test , so I am trying to keep it generic and as simple as possible. But that worked a treat . Thanks